# Java Scanner Reading an input line

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I was wondering how can I make a scanner in java that will read a line that you input.  For example:

```
package first.test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int binaryout;

        System.out.println("This converts base 10 numbers to binary numbers.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your Base 10 Number:");
        //I WANT THE INPUT TO GO HERE!!!!!!!!

       }
}
```

Any help would be great!

EDIT: Well, looking back at this question, the answer is blatantly obvious, do a google search. yes i did, but the problem is that i was such a noob, i couldnt modify or apply ideas to my projects. sorry for the inconvenience. if there are any ideas on how to edit the question to make it relevant, that would be great. because its just so bad, i dont know how.

Comment: Did you try a simple google search? You are going to get at least a million working examples.

Comment: i didnt find one that was specific to my needs, but i did find alot of examples that help with like reading files and stuff

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You might want to read the FAQ about about this site: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

I'd also suggest reading the "How to ask a good question" portion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

In particular, make sure you can answer "yes" to "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?".  If you have searched, let us know what you've tried.  It helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `input.nextLine();`? Or if you know it's base 10 then `input.nextInt()` or if it's longer `input.nextLong()`. In the future your best starting place is the java documentation especially since you already knew the class that you were trying to make use of. If you look at the docs for Scanner (and maybe search the page for 'line') you'll find what you were looking for:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Comment: thanks. ima noob when it comes to java so this was great. thanks a lot

Comment: would you be able to give an example on context on how it would be used?

Comment: You already set up your scanner called input. Now just use `int number = input.nextInt()` to get your input as an int into the variable number

Comment: `number = input.nextInt();` just assigns the number to the variable. If you want to print out a binary representation you would then do: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));`

Comment: what does the `(**integer.toBinaryString**(number));` do?

Comment: Well your program says it is converting your numbers from base 10 to binary. `Integer.toBinaryString(number);` where number is your number variable does this for you and returns a string of 0's and 1's that represent your number in binary

Comment: ok. so this converts my number variable to binary? so how do i print it out?

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));` both converts it and then prints it.